# Xampp - MySQL is running and showing green, but unable to connect phpMyAdmin in browser

Tags: phpmyadmin

I recently updated my windows after restarting of my laptop, i started xampp, Apache and MySQL both are running and it's showing green but i'm unable to login to phpmyadmin, i'm getting access denied.
Please find the below images for your references and i'm getting below errors.

[Xampp Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZgnq.png)

[Phpmyadmin Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QSaT.png)

I need to run mysql and need to access phpmyadmin

Resolved.
Click on Config next to mysql, and open my.ini and follow below steps

```
# The MySQL server
default-character-set=utf8mb4
[mysqld]
skip-grant-tables   <<<--- Add this line
port=3306
```